# Castle ActiveRecord fails to detect DAO field in some queries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, castle-activerecord

This query works fine:

```
DetachedCriteria filter = DetachedCriteria
                          .For(typeof(NotificationRecord), "nr")
                          .Add(Expression.Eq("nr.Submission.Id", 5));

return ActiveRecordMediator<NotificationRecord>.FindAll(filter);
```

This query fails with the exception message: `could not resolve property: Submission.IsScheduledForNotification of: NotificationRecord`

```
DetachedCriteria filter = DetachedCriteria
                          .For(typeof(NotificationRecord), "nr")
                          .Add(Expression.Eq("nr.Submission.IsScheduledForNotification", true));

return ActiveRecordMediator<NotificationRecord>.FindAll(filter);
```

To ensure ActiveRecord is recognizing `IsScheduledForNotification`, I do a simple query on the actual `Submission` object using the `IsScheduledForNotification` as filter like so and it works

```
ActiveRecordMediator<Submission>.Exists(Expression.Eq("IsScheduledForNotification", true));
```

Can someone say why this should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CreateAlias()` to indicate the joined entity, e.g.:

```
DetachedCriteria
.For(typeof(NotificationRecord), "nr")
.CreateAlias("nr.Submission", "s")
.Add(Expression.Eq("s.IsScheduledForNotification", true));
```

You don't need this for the `nr.Submission.Id` query because there is no join there.